# How to bring up drumroll sound at login screen in 20.04

Tags: sound, login-screen

As the title says, I've started using Ubuntu again after using other distros for quite some time, but I'm starting to feel a bit nostalgic for the old drumroll sound (system-ready.ogg) that would play when you would reach the login screen. I see there's no straightforward way to enable it so I was hoping to get some ideas on what I can do.

Comment: What are your current desktop environment and graphical login manager?

Answer (score 1):

Historically the *system-ready* sound was contained in *ubuntu-sounds* package which is used by *unity-greeter*.

To get drum sounds you have to install LightDM and configure it to use Unity login greeter.
Analysis of the logs gives a clue that we need to install PolicyKit service.
So the complete reproducible command is below:

```
sudo apt-get install lightdm unity-greeter ubuntu-sounds policykit-1 --no-install-recommends
# select lightdm in ncurses window
```

Then reboot and enjoy.

---

For Ubuntu MATE 20.04 LTS the setup is different. It uses *slick-greeter*.
To configure it we need to create special configuration file and install `ubuntu-sounds` package and specify path to the sound file:

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-sounds

cat <<EOF | sudo tee /etc/lightdm/slick-greeter.conf
[Greeter]
play-ready-sound=/usr/share/sounds/ubuntu/stereo/system-ready.ogg
EOF
```

Then reboot and enjoy.

Comment: Nice answer. There's a lot to be said of the well-thought out all-inclusiveness of Unity in a simple format unlike the complexity of Gnome bells and whistles requiring extensions. Indeed you could use Unity out of the box with Compiz and never have to install Compiz Session Manger. Even with Unity Tweak Tools installed.

Answer (score 0):

The old Ubuntu sound theme is available as a `.deb` package directly from Ubuntu itself, here:

http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/u/ubuntu-sounds/

You can install it -- remove any newer one first, if present -- and choose it using `dconf-editor`, as described here:

https://www.debugpoint.com/how-install-sound-themes-ubuntu-linux/

Note, as ever in Linux, theme names are case-sensitive: the name is "ubuntu" and not "Ubuntu".