# How to add Startup AND Shutdown sounds to Ubuntu 20.04 LTS?

Tags: shutdown, startup

*EDIT: Got my custom startup sounds to work. Question for shutdown sounds is still on the table.*

Title says it all.

**I have made use of the well-known `gtk-canberra-play` command to Startup Applications to play the startup sound. However, I tried to dig around for `usr/share/sounds/ubuntu/stereo` to no luck; I think that directory no longer exists in 20.04.**

**I want to specify a specific OGG file for it to play - how will I be able to do that?**

Also, is there a way to add shutdown sounds to Ubuntu? If so, how?

All answers are appreciated.

Comment: There are two other similar directories that have `stereo/` in them: `/usr/share/sounds/freedesktop/` and `/usr/share/sounds/Yaru/`. I'm not sure what you're doing with those directories, and I'm not an audio expert, but have you tried either of those for what you're looking for?

Comment: My own start includes `paplay /usr/share/sounds/ubuntu/stereo/desktop-login.ogg` with that sound coming from the package `ubuntu-sounds`

Comment: @UbeentoUbuntu I have worked my way towards getting my custom startup sound to work by finding what sound does gtk-canberra-play play on startup, and replacing it with my own. It works now. Thanks anyways

guiverc, I've read up that paplay is not a reliable method of playing startup sounds moving forward with 20.04 LTS.

Anywhos, now that I managed to get startup sounds to work, I shall edit the OP to ask for help about shutdown sounds.

Comment: I'm using & have used the method I describe for many releases up to and including *jammy* or what I'm using now. It works on *focal* no different to other releases; `paplay` is pulse-audio-play and thus is rather reliable in my experience (11.04 -> 21.10 & *jammy* thus far)

Comment: Login sound part is here - https://askubuntu.com/a/1349387/66509 . For logout further analysis is needed.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the plasma desktop, you can add a startup  sound, bu going to notifications, then to applications-configure-system services-plasma workspace-configure events- A screen will have a list of sounds that you can play for different things. One will be a log on OGG and one will be a log off OGG. Put it where it reads "play a sound; make sure that the box to the left is checked.